# how to pass graphql list to mutation in apollo in react js

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, mutation

I have a mutation like this:

```
orderAdd(products: [ProductInput],restaurant: RestaurantInput)
```

in **graphql** and i want to pass parameter to it in **Apollo** in **react js**
like this:

```
 mutation orderAdd ($products: [ProductInput]!, $restaurant: RestaurantInput!)
{
    orderAdd(products: $products, restaurant: $restaurant)
      {
        errors
        order {
          id
          createdAt
          products {
            id
            name
            price
            quantity
            totalPrice
          }
          rate {
            speed
            service
            flavor
          }
       }
    }
  }
;
```

but it does not work i think the problem with **graphql** list because the parameter products is type of 
 `products: { type: new GraphQLList(productInputType) }`,
please can you tell me how to pass **graphql** list to mutation in **apollo**?

Comment: Just looking at what you posted, the variables you're passing in to your operation don't match what you're passing in to orderAdd ($totalPrice is missing). However, you should edit your question and provide additional details: what do you mean when you say it "does not work" -- what error message are you receiving? It would also be helpful to see your code for the graphql HOC.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass list in mutation like this

```js
orderAdd(products: [{ProductInput1},{ProductInput2}],restaurant: RestaurantInput){.. }
```

Hope, this will help you.

Comment: i want to know how to declare it in apollo
mutation orderAdd ($products: [ProductInput]!, $restaurant: RestaurantInput!)
in this line i think [productinput]! it is not correct